# JCEf not launching on MAC in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, chromium-embedded

I have built jcef for MAC with following versions
MAC 10.13.4

Xcode 9.3

java 1.8.0_171 and 1.8.0_191 both tried

JCEF built from instructions https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)

I created an eclipse project and imported all the jars, copied Release folder in the project, then I am trying to run following MainFrame.java example

```
package jcefdemo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.cef.CefApp;
import org.cef.CefApp.CefAppState;
import org.cef.CefClient;
import org.cef.CefSettings;
import org.cef.OS;
import org.cef.browser.CefBrowser;
import org.cef.handler.CefAppHandlerAdapter;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;


public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5570653778104813836L;
    private final JTextField address_;
    private final CefApp cefApp_;
    private final CefClient client_;
    private final CefBrowser browser_;
    private final Component browerUI_;


    private MainFrame(String startURL, boolean useOSR, boolean isTransparent) {
        CefApp.addAppHandler(new CefAppHandlerAdapter(null) {
            @Override
            public void stateHasChanged(org.cef.CefApp.CefAppState state) {
                if (state == CefAppState.TERMINATED) System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.windowless_rendering_enabled = useOSR;
        cefApp_ = CefApp.getInstance(settings);
        client_ = cefApp_.createClient();
        browser_ = client_.createBrowser(startURL, useOSR, isTransparent);
        browerUI_ = browser_.getUIComponent();


        address_ = new JTextField(startURL, 100);
        address_.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                browser_.loadURL(address_.getText());
            }
        });

        getContentPane().add(address_, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(browerUI_, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setSize(800, 600);
        setVisible(true);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                CefApp.getInstance().dispose();
                dispose();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Perform startup initialization on platforms that require it.
        try {
        String libpath =  "<path to project>/jcefdemo/Release"; 
        System.setProperty("java.library.path",libpath);
        final Field sysPathsField = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
        sysPathsField.setAccessible(true);
        sysPathsField.set(null, null);

         if (!CefApp.startup()) {
           System.out.println("Startup initialization failed!");
            return;
        }
        boolean useOsr = false;
        new MainFrame("http://www.google.com", true, true);
        System.out.println("Startup ");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**but getting below error**

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1349)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1324)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1348)
    at org.cef.CefApp.<init>(CefApp.java:164)
    at org.cef.CefApp.getInstance(CefApp.java:215)
    at org.cef.CefApp.getInstance(CefApp.java:193)
    at jcefdemo.JCefBrowser.<init>(JCefBrowser.java:34)
    at jcefdemo.JCefBrowser.main(JCefBrowser.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.cef.CefApp.N_PreInitialize()Z
    at org.cef.CefApp.N_PreInitialize(Native Method)
    at org.cef.CefApp.access$0(CefApp.java:548)
    at org.cef.CefApp$1.run(CefApp.java:157)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
initialize on Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] with library path /Users/admin/Documents/test/jcefdemo/Release

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1349)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1324)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1348)
    at org.cef.CefApp.initialize(CefApp.java:418)
    at org.cef.CefApp.createClient(CefApp.java:309)
    at jcefdemo.JCefBrowser.<init>(JCefBrowser.java:35)
    at jcefdemo.JCefBrowser.main(JCefBrowser.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.cef.CefApp.N_Initialize(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/cef/handler/CefAppHandler;Lorg/cef/CefSettings;)Z
    at org.cef.CefApp.N_Initialize(Native Method)
    at org.cef.CefApp.access$5(CefApp.java:549)
    at org.cef.CefApp$3.run(CefApp.java:411)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.cef.handler.CefClientHandler.N_CefClientHandler_CTOR()V
    at org.cef.handler.CefClientHandler.N_CefClientHandler_CTOR(Native Method)
    at org.cef.handler.CefClientHandler.<init>(CefClientHandler.java:39)
    at org.cef.CefClient.<init>(CefClient.java:90)
    at org.cef.CefApp.createClient(CefApp.java:314)
    at jcefdemo.JCefBrowser.<init>(JCefBrowser.java:35)
    at jcefdemo.JCefBrowser.main(JCefBrowser.java:57)
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem?